# Не получается расставить блоки DIV

Tags: html, css

Изображение [link text](http://s017.radikal.ru/i402/1409/f6/fbd7fc3588d9.png)

Помогите, пожалуйста, советом.

На изображении показано, как должны стоять блоки, но у меня не получается их выстроить таким образом. Пробовал и Float, и position.

HTML:

```
<DIV class="wrap">
    <div class="red"></div>
    <div class="red"></div>
    <div class="blue"></div>
    <div class="red"></div>
    <div class="red"></div>
</DIV>
```

CSS:

```
.wrap {
    width: 940px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    }
.wrap .red {
    background: #f00;
    width: 300px;
    height: 150px;
    margin: 10px;
    }
.wrap .blue {
    background: #00f;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    margin: 10px;
    }
```

Как правильно дописать CSS, подскажите, пожалуйста.
Блоки статичные, наполняются различной инфой, но размер не меняют.

[image]

Comment: Без [дополнительных элементов][1] разметки, это будет сделать не просто. Даже если высчитать нужные значения для одного разрешения экрана устройств, то далеко не факт, что на других будет отображаться корректно.

   [1]:http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/xj7sze2L/1/

Comment: Это будет отображаться только на одном экране, статическая ширина до 1200 пикселей.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А почему бы не переверстать с использованием `display: table-cell`?

```css
.wrap {
    width: 940px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.wrap .col {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
.wrap .red {
    background: #f00;
    width: 300px;
    height: 150px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.wrap .blue {
    background: #00f;
    width: 300px;
    height: 310px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="col">
        <div class="red"></div>
        <div class="red"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <div class="blue"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <div class="red"></div>
        <div class="red"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: А есть какин-нибудь идеи по rowspan для центрального синего блока?

Comment: Так rowspan не нужен.
Я бы как-то так сделал — http://jsfiddle.net/syzho9n8/

Comment: @Michael-F, никакого colspan для варианта, который предложил  @Detonator, не нужно. Но этот вариант так же, как и мой в комментарии выше, требует дополнительной разметки, которую вы отметаете в принципе. Единственное, что могу вам предложить, - это использовать свойство **column-count**. [Смотрите пример][1]. Решение не кроссбраузерное, но это, как я уже понял, вас не очень-то волнует.

   [1]:http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/vn89peLv/2/

Comment: Точно, как же я сразу не додумался - экранирование блоков!!!
Вот я ***! Спасибо @Detonator !
Спасибо всем, кто подключился к вопросу.